# Align equation system

Tags: math-mode, alignat

I already successfully numbered the equation system correct, but how do I get rid of the big character spacing? I already use `alignat*`. If I take one `&` away, the roman numbers aren't among themselves anymore :(.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
%================
%PAKETE
%================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
%\usepackage{subfig} %Um mehrere Grafiken via {subfigure} in ein eine {figure}-Umgebung zu tun
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Anpassung des Zeichensatzs (Sonderzeichen)
\usepackage{romannum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}\\
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(s)\\
        \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix*} + t\begin{pmatrix*} 2\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix*} &= \begin{pmatrix*} 2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix*} + s \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\-1\\2 \end{pmatrix*}\\
        \text{I.} &\quad& 1+2t &= 2+s &\quad&\\
        \text{II.} && 1+t &= -s &&\\
        \text{III.} && t  &= 2+2s &&\\
        \text{III. in II. :}\\
        1+2+2s &= -s & \vert \; + \; s \; \vert \; -3\\
        3s     &= -3 & \vert \; \div \; (-3)\\
        s      &= -1\\
    \end{alignat*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like: 
[image]

Comment: For your information, it is good practice to post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) (for instance, with less `\usepackage`s).

Comment: okay, thank you, what does mwe mean?

Comment: @LillienSabrinaGluch, Minimal Working Example. So, a piece of code (including preamble) to be compiled by us to solve your problem.

Comment: okay, i will do it in the future, thanks for the advice

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how to remove the big spaces between the Roman numerals and the equations? Would `leqno` equation numbering be a good solution?

Comment: yes, i am asking for removing the big spaces. i dont know leqno, how do i use it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do the two formulae on the bottom right mean? I’m not familiar with that notation.

Comment: this is a bit out of context. its analytical geometry and a example how to calculate the intersection between two straights. i havent finished the complete writing of it. the \verts on the right are a help for me, what i do to come to the next step of the equation. in german it means Operatorstrich. Hope this answeres your question

Comment: One other idea: would `\mathord{|}` to give `|` the spacing of a variable work better for you than a bunch of `\; \vert \;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one possible solution that creates the labels with `\tag*{}`, references them with `\ref{}` and uses the `leqno` package option of `amsmath`/`mathtools` to place them on the left.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros} % Free clone of Helvetica.

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}\\
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(s)\\
        \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix*} + t\begin{pmatrix*} 2\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix*} &= \begin{pmatrix*} 2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix*} + s \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\-1\\2 \end{pmatrix*}\\
        \label{eq:i}\tag*{I.} 1+2t &= 2+s &\quad&\\
        \label{eq:ii}\tag*{II.} 1+t &= -s &&\\
        \label{eq:iii}\tag*{III.} t  &= 2+2s &&\\
        \text{\ref{eq:iii} in \ref{eq:ii}:}\\
        1+2+2s &= -s & \vert \; + \; s \; \vert \; -3\\
        3s     &= -3 & \vert \; \div \; (-3)\\
        s      &= -1\\
    \end{alignat*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Document]

I’ve taken the liberty of simplifying your preamble considerably, but now it only runs in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  The same document body should still work with your preamble.  I’m afraid I don’t speak German, but your comments appear to be discussing what you need from each of those packages.  The newer TeX engines accept UTF-8 source and use Unicode encoding out of the box, and `unicode-math` declares all the symbols in `amssymb`, `textcomp`, and many other packages besides, so that one package can replace the majority of the preamble.  I’d seriously consider switching to it unless you’re forced to use PDFLaTeX.  I also allowed `mathtools` to include `amsmath` automatically and removed packages that are not needed for this example.

And here is a PDFTeX-compatible version:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}\\
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(s)\\
        \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix*} + t\begin{pmatrix*} 2\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix*} &= \begin{pmatrix*} 2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix*} + s \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\-1\\2 \end{pmatrix*}\\
        \label{eq:i}\tag*{I.} 1+2t &= 2+s &\quad&\\
        \label{eq:ii}\tag*{II.} 1+t &= -s &&\\
        \label{eq:iii}\tag*{III.} t  &= 2+2s &&\\
        \text{\ref{eq:iii} in \ref{eq:ii}:}\\
        1+2+2s &= -s & \vert \; + \; s \; \vert \; -3\\
        3s     &= -3 & \vert \; \div \; (-3)\\
        s      &= -1\\
    \end{alignat*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using ShareLaTeX, so i dont know if i should delete the packages i use and replace it with unicode-math

Comment: when i copy your solution in, i get an error while compiling :(

Comment: What happens when you replace my preamble with yours? I compiled with LuaLaTeX on TeX Live 2018.

Comment: "Package ucharcat Error: \UCharcat may only be used with xetex and luatex"
And so on, there are more errors because of this listed

Comment: i wish i could send a screenshot here in a comment

Comment: yes. hope there is a solution for my preamble :(

Comment: Actually, I just loaded up ShareLaTeX. In the menu, there’s an option to change your compiler to LuaLaTeX.

Comment: can i still make a pdf of the document after that?

Comment: Yes. I’ve confirmed that, when you set your compiler to LuaLaTeX, my MWE compiles to a PDF in ShareLaTeX. (You’d want to change the `\documentclass` back to get something printable, though. `standalone` is just for producing images to post online.)

Comment: Also, again, my document body should still work with your preamble.

Comment: hmm. now the output looks very weird. the numbers are on the right site now and the vektors are displaced, also the big spaces are still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77743/discussion-between-davislor-and-lillien-sabrina-gluch).

Answer (score 2):

I propose this other layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
%================
%PAKETE
%================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}\\
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        & & \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(s)\\
       \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix*} & &{\!}+ t\begin{pmatrix*} 2\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix*}&= \begin{pmatrix*} 2\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix*}\! + s \begin{pmatrix*} 1\\-1\\2 \end{pmatrix*}\\[1.5ex]
        \text{I.}\hspace{0.7em}& & 1+2t &= 2+s &\quad&\\
        \text{II.}\hspace{0.7em}& & 1+t &= -s &&\\
 \text{III.}\hspace{0.7em} && t &= 2+2s &&\\[1.5ex]
\text{III. in II. :}\hspace{0.7em} & \\[-0.5ex]
 & & \mathllap{1+2+2s} &= -s & & \mid + \; s \;\mid -3\\
& & 3s &= -3 & & \mid \div \; (-3)\\
 & & s &= -1
    \end{alignat*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]